# Laravel 5 redirect function source code

Tags: php, laravel

Where is Laravel 5 `redirect` function source code?

I use `ag "function redirect"` to search where is it definition but I got nothing.

So I want to know where it is, why and how.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework https://laravel.com/api/5.4/

Answer (score 2):

It's in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`:

```
function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    if (is_null($to)) {
        return app('redirect');
    }

    return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `ag` ignores vcs ignores(.gitignore, .hgignore; still obey .ignore), now I got what I want: using `ag --php --skip-vcs-ignores "function redirect\("`

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
604:    function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)

vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/RedirectableUrlMatcherInterface.php
30:    public function redirect($path, $route, $scheme = null);

vendor/symfony/routing/Tests/Fixtures/RedirectableUrlMatcher.php
22:    public function redirect($path, $route, $scheme = null)
```